# Uncaught Error EmberJS and Polyfills

Tags: javascript, ember.js, polyfills

I cloned an Ember project and when running it throws me the following error:

```
loader.js:247 Uncaught Error: Could not find module `@ember/polyfills` imported from `radio/initializers/viewport-config`
    at missingModule (loader.js:247)
    at findModule (loader.js:258)
    at Module.findDeps (loader.js:168)
    at findModule (loader.js:262)
    at requireModule (loader.js:24)
    at index.js:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at exports.default (index.js:15)
    at Module.callback (app.js:13)
    at Module.exports (loader.js:106)
```

Previously I had installed the ember client, phantomJS and I made both a bower install and npm install of the following files:

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "radio",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for radio goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test",
    "deploy": "**",
    "deploy-prod": "**"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.2",
    "broccoli-sass": "^0.7.0",
    "ember-ajax": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli": "2.7.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.6",
    "ember-cli-bourbon": "1.2.2",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-google-analytics": "1.5.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-meta-tags": "3.0.1",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "2.2.1",
    "ember-cli-pace": "0.1.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
    "ember-cli-slick": "1.0.14",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "^2.7.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "1.1.1",
    "ember-lazy-image": "0.0.15",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-local-storage": "1.3.1",
    "ember-moment": "6.1.0",
    "ember-resize": "0.0.17",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-responsive": "1.2.7",
    "ember-social": "0.3.0",
    "ember-youtube": "0.8.2",
    "liquid-fire": "0.24.1",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "radio",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "~2.7.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.1",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.1.0",
    "bourbon": "4.2.6",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.6.0",
    "pace": "^1.0.2",
    "blob-polyfill": "^1.0.20150320"
  }
}
```

I have been installing npm / bower several libraries to solve problems about polyfills but I did not find a solution, does anyone know how to solve this problem? Greetings.

Comment: Is the project OSS? If yes, may we can get a link to the git repo? Maybe its not in a valid state. I specifically think it should upgrade to `ember-cli-babel: "^6.6.0"`, and maybe some other stuff itself as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to pin down your problem without the actual source code of the file mentioned in the error message.

You could be using an ember addon, which uses the new module structure. You have to either:

1. update your ember version to a version which supports this new model structure (@ember namespace).
2. use an older version of the dependent addon, which does not use the new module structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ember-lazy-image, it seems that it's not working properly. i've recently had that issue